# Change PDF file name in odoo v12

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have created a custom report in odoo v12, and here is my report action

```
 <report id="report_custom"
                model="report.wizard"
                string="Doc1"
                report_type="qweb-pdf"
                name="my_module.my_template"
                file="my_module.my_template"
                menu="False"
                multi="False" attachment_use = "False"
                paperformat="paperformat_euro_custom"
                print_report_name="('Doc2-'+ object.partner_id.name +'.pdf')"/>
               />
```

Now when the report get printed I wanted to name a file like Doc2-partnet-name
I always got the 'Doc1' name declared in the string.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From which model do you print this report?

Comment: @Ibrahim Rahimi, from wizard generated in 'account.invoice' model

Answer (score 0):

Try print_report_name as below

```
print_report_name="'Doc2 - %s' % (object.partner_id.name)"
```

Comment: same problem ..., always got the string value printing , I tried also by adding  print_report_name="Doc2" , but value is Doc1